# Modifying Individual User $PATH in Fish Shell

Tags: path, fish

I'm trying to change the $PATH of an individual user in fish-shell so that berryconda runs before default python.

I've found my way to the config.fish file and added what the file says to add for login shells.

```
if status --is-login
set PATH /root/berryconda3/bin/python $PATH
end
```

My issue is this doesn't seem to change the $PATH at all and I also only want it to occur for one specific user anyway so I don't think this is correct. How can I go about changing the $PATH of an individual user in fish-shell.

Comment: Is `/root/berryconda3/bin/python` the executable file, or is it a directory where the python executable file exists? PATH only contains directories.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to the user's *~/.config/fish/config.fish* file:

```
contains /root/berryconda3/bin/python $PATH
or set -gx PATH /root/berryconda3/bin/python $PATH
```

Using `if status is-login` to guard the modification is reasonable if you only want it to be done for the first shell launched by a terminal. However, it may never be true if the terminal is configured to launch the shell without marking it a login shell.

Also, that point points to a file in the root acount home dir. That may not be accessible by a non-root user and in any case it is bad idea to have non-root accounts depending on files in the root user home dir.